# permission Problem while using popen in C (linux)

Tags: c, linux, permissions

I am trying to access `/proc/net/dev` file with `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0` privileges using `popen`. The code is as fairly as:

```
main(){
FILE *f;
f=popen("/proc/net/dev","r");
pclose(f);}
```

logged in as a root,after compiling & running the program, I get this:

> sh: /proc/net/dev: Permission denied.

Can you please help me through this problem?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popen()` is for opening a pipe to another process, the path provided must be to an executable file, not a device entry. You probably want `open()` or `fopen()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way, popen is to open a pipe from an application.  `/proc/net/dev` is not an application but is a file.  Try looking at fopen instead.

```
f=fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r");
fclose(f);
```

Comment: As a side note; you're getting permission denied because popen is attempting to execute /proc/net/dev which does not have execute permissions on (which it is not supposed to either).

Answer (score 0):

use read; for more info type man read in a terminal

Comment: Read requires an existing open file descriptor.

Comment: Later edit: Sorry, it's 6 AM and I'm a little sleepy :) He tried to open, not to read. I understand.